# Weird "borrowed value does not live long enough" in generics

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

This simple piece of code is driving me nuts:

```rust
pub fn load_any<'a, T, K>(&self, key: K) -> Result<Option<T>, kv::Error> where
    T: 'a + Persistent + Debug + Serialize + for<'de> Deserialize<'de>,
    K: 'a + kv::Key<'a>,
{
    let bucket = self.store.bucket::<K,kv::Bincode<T>>(Some(T::bucket_name()))?;
    bucket
        .get(key)?.unwrap();
    Ok(None)
}
```

the error is:

```
  --> src/persist.rs:47:9
   |
42 |       pub fn load_any<'a, T, K>(&self, key: K) -> Result<Option<T>, kv::Error> where
   |                       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
47 |           bucket
   |           -^^^^^
   |           |
   |  _________borrowed value does not live long enough
   | |
48 | |             .get(key)?.unwrap();
   | |_____________________- argument requires that `bucket` is borrowed for `'a`
...
51 |       }
   |       - `bucket` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I tried almost everything (including cloning `key` and messing up with lifetimes) but I can't understand how to make it work.
The real code was different (I obviously do something with value returned by get) but error is the same.
Get result is not returned and bucket is used only to call `get()`.
Rust compiler complains that `bucket` is dropped while still borrowed but nothing is borrowing it.

The same code works perfectly replacing the generic `K` with a typed var:

```rust
pub fn load_str<'a, T>(&self, key: &str) -> Result<Option<T>, kv::Error> where
    T: 'a + Persistent + Debug + Serialize + for<'de> Deserialize<'de>,
{
    let bucket = self.store.bucket::<&str,kv::Bincode<T>>(Some(T::bucket_name()))?;
    bucket
        .get(key)?.unwrap();
    Ok(None)
   // This code works perfectly
}
```

Code uses the [kv](https://crates.io/crates/kv) library.

Comment: Can you move your solution into an answer? This way it'll fit the Q&A structure of this site and be easier to read/vote/everything

Comment: [`Bucket::get`](https://docs.rs/kv/0.22.0/kv/struct.Bucket.html#method.get) only accepts `Key`s tied to its lifetime, but since `'a` derived outside the function via `key` will always live longer than `bucket` defined inside the function, the compiler tries to bend itself backwards attempting to make it work. I don't have a solution since the way around that is often the `for<'a>` syntax.

Comment: Exactly: the ```for<'a>``` is the only solution. The problem is in the kv library itself: i opened a PR (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I modified code as follows:

```rust
pub fn load_any<T, K>(&self, key: K) -> Result<Option<T>, kv::Error> where
    T: Persistent + Debug + Serialize + for<'de> Deserialize<'de>,
    K: for<'k> kv::Key<'k>,
{
    let bucket = self.store.bucket::<K,kv::Bincode<T>>(Some(T::bucket_name()))?;
    bucket
        .get(key)?.unwrap();
    Ok(None)
}
```

I used the "for any lifetime" used even in `T` definition.
I guess this make the compile "ignore" the lifetime of `Key` that is not needed because it's not borrowed.

But the problem now is *using* the method:

```rust
error: implementation of `kv::types::Key` is not general enough
   --> src/main.webapp.rs:146:30
    |
146 |       println!("{:?}", persist.load::<&str,DisyStat>("qqq"));
    |                                ^^^^ implementation of `kv::types::Key` is not general enough
    | 
   ::: /opt/rust/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/kv-0.22.0/src/types.rs:7:1
    |
7   | / pub trait Key<'a>: Sized + AsRef<[u8]> {
8   | |     /// Convert from Raw
9   | |     fn from_raw_key(r: &'a Raw) -> Result<Self, Error>;
10  | |
...   |
14  | |     }
15  | | }
    | |_- trait `kv::types::Key` defined here
    |
    = note: `kv::types::Key<'0>` would have to be implemented for the type `&str`, for any lifetime `'0`...
    = note: ...but `kv::types::Key<'1>` is actually implemented for the type `&'1 str`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

It turned out that the problem is in the kv library enforcing `'a` lifetime on self for some methods.

I fixed it and opened a PR: [Removed 'a lifetime from get() and contains() methods](https://github.com/zshipko/rust-kv/pull/19)